# problems with clamtk

Tags: lubuntu, clamav, clamtk

I´ve installed clamtk. So far I had just clamav, which has really been working well, but now I wanted a GUI too.
But now I noticed the following:
When looking at the number of virus-definitions clamtk says: "antivirus-signatures: 22374".
Clamscan (when started in a terminal) however says: "Known viruses: 4936270". What´s the difference now?
The thing is, however, when looking at ~/.clamtk/history/ the log-file says: "ClamTk, v5.20  Sun Oct 16 13:03:31 2016  ClamAV-Signaturen: 4941635". That´s weird. What now?
22374 or 4941635 AV-signatures?

Furthermore: when starting clamtk I get the message "update available". When clicking on "checking for updates" no new signatures are downloaded. The respective number (22374) remains the same. 
Internet-connection is working. In the settings I clicked on "I want to update the signatures myself". I also started clamtk as sudo.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks a lot.
Rosika

P.S.: 
System: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)

Comment: I guess it depends if you count the Viruses by common signatures, or count every little change as a different one!

Comment: Tnx Ken. That would at least explain the huge difference in counts.